# Trigger an event when a download starts

Tags: java, android, download

Is there any way to listen for/capture the beginning of a download (not completing it, as I want the user to make a decision before the download begins)? The download will be user triggered (via browser or app, for example).

Comment: How are you planning to do the download? Using the DownloadManager class?

Comment: The download will be user triggered (via browser or app, for example).